# Why does abstracting html from plugin code result in loss of access to wordpress functions?

Tags: php, include

When defining the callback that produces the HTML content for an admin settings page, I'd like to abstract the HTML into a separate file, but the HTML uses some wordpress functions, specifically current_user_can and screen_icon. These are claimed to be undefined when called through the included file but work fine inline.

```
function admin_menu_page_content() {

        if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
            wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
        }
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">  

            <?php include(plugins_url('plugin_name/forms/admin_form.php')) ?>
        </div> 
        <?php
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`plugin_dir_path()`](http://queryposts.com/function/plugin_dir_path/) to include executable files. `plugins_url()` returns the web address, that’s not what you need.

```
<?php include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'forms/admin_form.php') ?>
```